# Graph Theory, graph and complement question

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-writing

Which is the easier method to prove such a statement, would it be contradiction or induction?

If in a graph, each vertex has an even degree, how should we go about to prove that in the complement of G, the same parity applies to all vertex degrees?

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $d$ is degree for $v$ in $G$ then the degree $d'$ of $v$ in $G'$ is $n-1-d$.

---

So, if $$d_1 \equiv d_2\equiv \cdots \equiv d_n \equiv 0\pmod 2$$ then $$n-1-d_1\equiv n-1-d_2\equiv \cdots \equiv n-1-d_n \equiv n-1\pmod 2$$

Comment: so no need to use contradiction or induction to prove this? And what is mod 2?

Comment: Look on web for modular arithmetic